# DateDetailView of django 1.5

Tags: django, generics, view

I am writing a new blog with django 1.5 but in my template i don't have link related to my entry object.

My Model

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article_archive_date_detail',kwargs = {'year':self.pub_date.strftime("%Y"),
                                          'month':self.pub_date.strftime("%b").lower(),
                                          'day':self.pub_date.strftime("%d"),
                                          'slug':self.slug})
```

My url:

```
  url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',DateDetailView.as_view(queryset=Article.objects.filter(status=Article.LIVE_STATUS), date_field="pub_date"),name="article_archive_date_detail"),
```

The template:

```
{% for entry in latest %}      
   <a class="readmore" href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}">Read more ...</a> &nbsp; 
{% endfor %}
```

What have i forgotten?

Comment: What is `latest` in template?

Comment: come from ArchiveIndexView.as_view

Comment: In `get_absolute_url` you are using `kargs`, it should be `kwargs`. Is that typo in post?